# CSS Layout Vertical-Aligned Scroll Container

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to design the following layout in CSS3:

The blue container should have a padding of 1% to
top, right, bottom and left of html/body (painted black here).
The orange container shall be scrollable.
The green containers shall have a height in percentage like all other containers, too
.
[image]

My CSS code looks like this so far:

```
<style>
.html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.containerbox {
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    paddding: 1% 1% 1% 1%; // not working yet
    // todo: horizontal alignment
    // todo: vertical alignment
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%%;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%%;
}
</style>
```

And this is my html code regarding my CSS above:

```
<div class="containerbox">

<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have my code fragment. I will post it.

Comment: you have misspelled padding, and instead of using four same value you can use one        padding: 1% ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on something. You can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3kx7nsyz/3/).

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.blue-container{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.green{
    background-color: green;
}
    
.green.big{
    height: 15%;
}
    
.green.small{
    height: 10%;
}
    
.orange{
    height: 72%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 1% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-container">
    <div class="green big"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="green small"></div>
</div>
```

P.S. You just have to find the right value for the colors.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5p1j25c/) of exactly this.

HTML

```
<div>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
        Lorem ipsum
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*,*:before,*:after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #3F47CA;
    border: 10px solid #000;
}

div{
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
}

header{
    height: 12%;
    background-color: #B5E51D;
}

main{
    height: calc(80% - 20px);
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background-color: #FFC90D;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

footer{
    height: 8%;
    background-color: #B5E51D;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    min-height: 100%;
}
.blue{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
}
.green{
    height: 20%; /*of the screen height*/
}
.orange{
    height: 30%; /*of the screen height*/
    overflow-y: scroll; /*scroll when content's height is more that container's height*/
}
```